# Can sound output be enabled on UTM Mac m1

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtual-machine

I have installed ubuntu on my UTM on Mac m1. When I go to the setting the ubuntu vm, I see that sound is not enabled. When I check the checkbox for sound hardware, I got multiple options for the audio card, none of which work. What the issue is that I don't get any internet on the vm. Is there any way I can enable the audio perfectly?